# Time-limited aggregation with publish-subscribe in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to implement the following using Spring Integration with DSL and lambda:

Given a message, send it to `N` consumers (via `publish-subscribe`). Wait for limited time and return all results that have arrived form consumers (`<= N`) during that interval.

Here is an example configuration I have so far:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@ComponentScan
public class ExampleConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata poller() {
        return Pollers.fixedRate(1000).maxMessagesPerPoll(1).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel publishSubscribeChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe(splitterExecutorService()).applySequence(true).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor splitterExecutorService() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executorService = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

        executorService.setCorePoolSize(3);
        executorService.setMaxPoolSize(10);

        return executorService;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel errorChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel channel1() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel channel2() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel collectorChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public TransformerChannel1 transformerChannel1() {
        return new TransformerChannel1();
    }

    @Bean
    public TransformerChannel2 transformerChannel2() {
        return new TransformerChannel2();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(errorChannel())
                .handle(m -> System.err.println("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] " + m.getPayload()))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow channel1Flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(publishSubscribeChannel())
                .transform("1: "::concat)
                .transform(transformerChannel1())
                .channel(collectorChannel())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow channel2Flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(publishSubscribeChannel())
                .transform("2: "::concat)
                .transform(transformerChannel2())
                .channel(collectorChannel())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow splitterFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(requestChannel())
                .channel(publishSubscribeChannel())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow collectorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(collectorChannel())
                .resequence(r -> r.releasePartialSequences(true),
                        null)
                .aggregate(a ->
                        a.sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                                .groupTimeout(500)
                        , null)
                .get();
    }

}
```

`TransformerChannel1` and `TransformerChannel2` are sample consumers and have been implemented with just a sleep to emulate delay.

The message flow is:

```
 splitterFlow -> channel1Flow \
              -> channel2Flow / -> collectorFlow
```

Everything seem to work as expected, but I see warnings like:

> Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply

which is to be expected, given that partial result was returned.

Questions:

- Overall, is this a good approach?
- What is the right way to gracefully service or discard those delayed messages?
- How to deal with exceptions? Ideally I'd like to send them to `errorChannel`, but am not sure where to specify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the solution looks good. I guess it fits for the [`Scatter-Gather`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather) pattern. The implementation is provided since version `4.1`.

From other side there is on more option for the `aggregator` since that version, too - `expire-groups-upon-timeout`, which is `true` for the aggregator by default. With this option as `false` you will be able to achieve your requirement to discard all those late messages. Unfortunately DSL doesn't support it [yet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/22). Hence it won't help even if you upgrade your project to use Spring Integration 4.1.

Another option for those "Reply message received but the receiving thread has already received a reply" is on the `spring.integraton.messagingTemplate.throwExceptionOnLateReply = true` option using `spring.integration.properties` file within the `META-INF` of one of jar.

Anyway I think that `Scatter-Gather` is the best solution for you use-case.
You can find [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jmx/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/monitor/ScatterGatherHandlerIntegrationTests.java) how to configure it from JavaConfig.

**UPDATE**

> What about exceptions and error channel?

Since you get deal already with the `throwExceptionOnLateReply` I guess you send a message to the `requestChannel` via `@MessagingGateway`. The last one has `errorChannel` option. From other side the `PublishSubscribeChannel` has `errorHandler` option, for which you can use `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` with your `errorChannel` as a default one.

BTW, don't forget that Framework provides `errorChannel` bean and the `endpoint` on it for the `LoggingHandler`. So, think, please, if you really need to override that stuff. The default `errorChannel` is `PublishSubscribeChannel`, hence you can simply add your own subscribers to it.

Comment: I added the `spring.integraton.messagingTemplate.throwExceptionOnLateReply = true` option to `application.properties` file and that did the trick too. Will look at the `Scatter-Gather` pattern next. What about exceptions and error channel? Thanks much!